# Prevent duplicate users in Firestore IOS

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, duplicates

I have three different login options through Firebase: email, facebook, google. I'm using Firestore to store the user information and don't want to have duplicate users. When users "sign up" for a new account, I want to check that the uid is not already in use. This is what I have, but it's still not working (you can have duplicate users with the same account and uid and everything):

```
    func addUserToFirestore(_ firstName:String, _ lastName:String, _ uid:String, _ email:String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document("uid")
        // check if user exists in firestore
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {
               if document.exists {
                // user exists. send to chats screen.
                print("User already exists. Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
                self.transitionToConvo()
              } else {
                // user does not exits. create a new user
                 print("Document does not exist. Create new user.")
                db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "uid":uid, "email":email ]) { (error) in
                        print("New user created in Firestore")
                    self.transitionToConvo()
                        
                        if error != nil {
                            // Show error message
                            print("Error saving user data to Firestore")
                        }
                    }
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

It gets called here (slightly different for facebook, google, and email). This is for Facebook signup/login:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            let firstName = user?.user.displayName
            let email = user?.user.email
            let lastName = ""
            guard let uid = user?.user.uid else { return }
            
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            } else {
                // Successfully logged in
                print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google uid: ", uid, "Now add user to Firestore if user is new.")
                
                // check if user already exists
                **self.addUserToFirestore(firstName ?? "", lastName, uid, email ?? "")**
                    }
                })
            }
```

As you can see, the uid is the same for both users:
[user 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8bx.jpg)
[user 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXtbb.jpg)
How can I get it to not have duplicate users? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

### Getting the user document

You are calling `let docRef = db.collection("users").document("uid")` which is fetching a document with ID "uid".  You need to pass in your user's ID.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
```

### Creating a new document

You are using `addDocument` so Cloud Firestore creates an auto generated ID which is not related to your user's ID.  Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document for details.

```
docRef.setData(data: [
  "firstname":firstName,
  "lastname":lastName,
  "uid":uid,
  "email":email
])
```

Comment: For the addDocument, I want to create a new user if the user does not exist after ```else```. Should I still make it ```setData```?

Comment: The exact code I used was:
```db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "uid":uid, "email":email]) { err in
if err != nil {
 // Show error message
print("Error saving user data to Firestore")
 } else {
print("New user created in Firestore")
self.transitionToConvo()
          }
}```

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you. When you use `setData` with a document ref, if the document doesn't already exist, it creates it, using the ID specified

Comment: You can replace `db.collection("users").document(uid)` with `docRef` as you've already set it earlier in your code (as shown in my answer)

Comment: Got it, thanks! Do you recommend preventing duplicates with uid or email? I'm not sure if I should use uid since I have multiple sign up options.

Comment: Normally, you would use the `uid`. If you have multiple sign-in methods, Firebase Auth normally assigns them to the same `uid`, unless you turn off this option.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.